# Typescript/Javascript custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am beginner and trying to refactor Javascript hooks into Typescript
but i cannot get button onClick event to change state. Can you please help?

This is useToggler component

```
import {useState} from 'react'

function useToggler (defaultOnValue=false){
    const[istoggledOn, setIsToggledOn] = useState(defaultOnValue);

    function clickHandler(){
        setIsToggledOn(prevState => !prevState)
    }

    return [istoggledOn, clickHandler]
}

export default useToggler
```

and this is App component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import useToggler from './compononets/useToggler'




const App: React.FC = () => {
    const[show, toggle]=useToggler(true);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={()=>toggle}>+</button>
            <span>{show? "yes!": "no!"}</span>
        </div>
    );

};

export default App;
```

Comment: You're not actually calling the toggle function. `onClick={() => toggle()}` (or, better yet, `onClick={toggle}`. This would not have worked even without TypeScript, so it's not the language migration making it difficult.

Comment: It's just a typo-level error. :-) You want `onClick={toggle}`, not `onClick={()=>toggle}`. `onClick={()=>toggle}` sets `onClick` to a function that returns the `click` function as its return value. `onClick={toggle}` sets `onClick` to `toggle`.

Comment: i have tried that and i get onClick error:
TS2322: Type 'boolean | (() => void)' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.   Type 'false' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a type error because you're returning an array in your `useToggler` function.

```
function useToggler (defaultOnValue=false){
    const[istoggledOn, setIsToggledOn] = useState(defaultOnValue);

    function clickHandler(){
        setIsToggledOn(prevState => !prevState)
    }

    return [istoggledOn, clickHandler] // Here
}
```

TypeScript interprets your return statement as meaning that you have an array of either `boolean` or `() => void`. This means that your `toggle` variable is identified as being of type `boolean | (() => void)` rather than `() => void`, hence the error message:

```
Not all constituents of type 'boolean | (() => void)' are callable
```

You resolve this by explicitly telling TypeScript that, no, you're not returning an array of `T | K` but rather a tuple of `T` and `K`. You could write out the type yourself, but newer versions of TypeScript can use `as const` to do this:

```
function useToggler (defaultOnValue=false){
    const[istoggledOn, setIsToggledOn] = useState(defaultOnValue);

    function clickHandler(){
        setIsToggledOn(prevState => !prevState)
    }

    return [istoggledOn, clickHandler] as const
}
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you Mr.Dan! I have been trying this for days...

Comment: Do you have any better or preferred way of doing this in Typescript?

Comment: This is, IMO, the best way to deal with returning Tuples in TypeScript.

Comment: What i wanted to ask is there a better way of refactoring this entire code in Typsescript, because this is basically Javascript with minor aditions?

Comment: That's all TypeScript is

Comment: thank you! If i am not bothering you and since i am learning can you show me how would you declare type to do this?

Comment: You would append a type declaration to the end of the function. `function useToggler(defaultOnValue = false): [boolean, () => void] {`

Comment: thank you! i Find this more understandable and readable than as Const.

Comment: I prefer `as const` just because explicitly typing the return type gets unwieldy after 2 or 3 items.

If my answer satisified your question, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the tick beneath the scoreline to the left of my answer :)